# different results for same method call

Tags: java

i do have a class CheckPrograminstallation(which is part of a eclipse plugin), with a method check, which checks whether a program is installed. It return true when installed and false otherwise.

```
public class CheckPrograminstallation{
    public static boolean check(String programname, String OsName)
            throws Exception {

        // Get installation path of programname
        String foundpath = "";
        String dirName = "";
        String line;
        String programpath = null;
        Process process = null;
        boolean IsInstalled = false;

        if (OsName.equals("Windows")) {
            try {
                // get Windows Directory first
                process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c echo %windir%");
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
                // read from stream 
                if ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    foundpath = line.toString();

                    // cut off "\Windows" from the found path
                    int last = foundpath.lastIndexOf("\\");
                    dirName = foundpath.subSequence(0, last).toString();
                    process = null;

                    // get program installation path
                    process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                            "cmd /c where /R " + dirName + " " + programname);

                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            process.getInputStream()));
                    if ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        programpath = line.toString();
                        System.out.println(programpath);
                        IsInstalled = true;

                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                DO SOMETHING);
            }
        }
```

When i call the method from a test class, it works.
But when i call the same method while running the Plugin:

```
...boolean isInstalledPscp;
   boolean IsWindows;
...
        if (IsWindows == true) {
            // for Windows: check if pscp is installed
            isInstalledPscp = CheckIfInstalled.check("pscp", "Windows");
        if (isInstalledPscp == false) {
            do something }
        }
```

**...it always returns false.** 
How can that be?

This has been driving me crazy for a whole day. Using .equals for String comparison, and still getting false as result. So **this is not a string comparison problem IMHO.**

Answer (score 0):

Change your string comparison from:

```
if (OsName == "Windows") {
```

To:

```
if (OsName.equals("Windows")) {
```

Since your if doesn't succeed, it never goes into if and hence it returns your false.

Comment: fixed that, still returns false

Comment: There could be multiple issues then. 1. code doesnt go in `if (IsWindows == true) {` and hence you land up with default value 2. your code doesnt go into `if ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {` (note its twice) and to set your variable to true it should enter in both the loops.

Answer (score 0):

You compare strings using the `equals()` method and not logical equals operator `==`

I also recommend that you follow java naming conventions and use variables names starting with lower case letters such as `osName` instead of `OsName`.

Comment: fixed it, still returns false

Answer (score 0):

Print out what are the paths that are returned inside your code (if any), I suspect that from within the plugin the runtime parameters are different.

Also maybe System.getEnv System.getProperties is a better way to find windows dir than starting a new process.

Comment: problem is that due to a bug i cannot use Self Hosting in Eclipse and without Self Hosting in Debug mode i have no idea how to show console outputs. I basically i cannot see the outputs. I cannot System, getproperties because i determine OS from ontology information

Comment: You can debug to a file. You are not using ontologies you are calling 'echo' and then 'where' from the command line.

Comment: determining type of Os from an Ontology, using 'where' to find out drive name.

Comment: Seriously, save your paths, and calls to the file and see what is happening. Again you are checking for existence of a file, just use File.exists for it.